# How is the event passed to this function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

Usually you have to calla function to pass it the event, how is the event passed to this function.

When the context menu is triggered, does it pass the event object to the function? Is this how it works?

```
window.oncontextmenu = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Yes, the event object is passed by the caller into the callback.

Comment: Yes, it passes the event object to the function -> you can log it to analyze the event.

Comment: "*Usually you have to call a function to pass it the event*" - not certain what you mean. Normally you don't call event handlers yourself.